# Cannot get/set IFormFile object from <input> tag of View

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an upload mechanism which looks like that in the View:

```
 <div  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" id="ProjectId" name="ProjectId" value="@Model.ProjectId"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="Name" name="Name" value= "" />
        <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="" />
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" asp-for="InputFile"  value="test" name="inputfile" onchange="ChooseInputFileButtonChanged(this);" id="ChooseInputFile"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="UploadInputFileButton" onclick="UploadInstallIntructions();"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my uploadinstructions() method, which gets called when the user pushes the 'Upload'button.

```
script>
    function UploadInstallIntructions() {
        var name = document.getElementById('SoftwareVersionName').value;
        var id = document.getElementById("Id").value;
        var iFormFile = document.getElementById("ChooseInputFile").files[0];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("UploadInputFile", "SoftwareVersion")',
            data: { projectId: @Model.ProjectId, Name: name, Id: id, inputFile: iFormFile},
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                window.location.href = response;
            }
        });
        return data;
    }
</script>
```

So this is a simple ajax call that calls a method on my controller with the specified arguments. My problem is that the last argument which should be the file data, of IFormFile type, so that I can work with it in my controller, doesn't get set. Is there a better way I can bind my IFormFile object in my view? Normally just the line :

```
input type="file" asp-for="InputFile" value="test" name="inputfile" onchange="ChooseInputFileButtonChanged(this);" id="ChooseInputFile"/>
```

should have worked to bind the IFormFile.

Edit: Not a duplicate of [how to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc), because my question was not about binding with FormData, but IFormFile not automattically getting created from the View.

Comment: You need t use `FormData` to post a file using ajax and set the correct ajax options. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried your solution and I did get a model back, but everything is null or 0 in it. The View code shown here is also in a partial view, if that helps to explain this behaviour. The UploadInstructions method is in the parent view, but that is how it would be regardless. So I still don't have the IFormFile.

Comment: Then you did not do it correctly:)

Comment: No, perhaps you missed something. It only worked when I added the data manually to that formData object: formData.append("SoftwareVersion.Name", name); etc

Comment: I did not miss anything. Read the link I gave you! And your code is adding a property `Name: name` to the response, not `SoftwareVersion.Name: name`! And the fact you assign `name` using the value of an element which does not even exist (there is no element with `id="SoftwareVersionName" in the code) suggesst you have other problems as well, not the least being that you do not understand model binding)

Comment: Again, you missed something in your answer. I fixed that syntax error that you are pointing out since yesterday, hence why I said that it worked when I added data manually. I understand model binding, but you probably didn't understand what the issue is.

Comment: I have not missed anything in that answer!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc)

Comment: Not a duplicate beacuse my specific issue was with IFormFile automatic binding on a property

Comment: It is a duplicate - you just replace `HttpPostedFileBase` with `IFormFile` in core-mvc

Comment: Nope, that didn't work, and it was the first thing I had tried to do before asking. Once again it shows you didn't clearly understand the question.

Comment: Sure, that's what the problem is. I'm not gonna argue anymore anyway,

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
    <form name="UpdateInstall" id="UpdateInstall" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" id="ProjectId" name="ProjectId" value="@Model.ProjectId"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="Name" name="Name" value= "" />
        <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="" />
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" asp-for="InputFile"  value="test" name="inputfile" onchange="ChooseInputFileButtonChanged(this);" id="ChooseInputFile"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="UploadInputFileButton" onclick="UploadInstallIntructions();"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

        <script>
            function UploadInstallIntructions() {
                var formData = new FormData($("#UpdateInstall")[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("UploadInputFile", "SoftwareVersion")',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        window.location.href = response;
                    }
                });
                return data;
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once i have done upload a image file like this..

```js
$('input[type="file"]').ajaxfileupload({
    'action': 'uploadFile.jsp',
    'cache': false,
    'onComplete': function(response) {
        $('#upload').hide();
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Alert!',
            message: 'Image Upload Successfully',
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Ok',
                action: function(dialog) {
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }]
        });

        var img_src = "../profilepic/" + response;
        setTimeout(5000);
        $("#image").attr("src", img_src);
    },
    'onStart': function() {
        $('#upload').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" name="datafile" accept="image/*"/><br/>
<div id="upload" style="display:none;">Uploading..</div>
```

If you wish to upload files like this, visit this link for
[jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js](https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js/)

Comment: It's just a piece of code, i have done in my case. I hope it will help you. I have used jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js for uploading the file.